# Quickly check if current user has access on target server

Tags: powershell

Whenever I use Get-Service with a user that does not have access on the target server it takes a large amount of time to timeout.
This is results in an increased amount of time necessary to run a script

Is there a way to find out if a user has access on the target sever? I want to use that kind of functionality in my script to decrease the amount of system resources necessary.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Access to a server in terms of permissions or just connectivity across the network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test-Connection (TechNet article [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315259.aspx)) sends ICMP packets to check for response across the network.  It is a PowerShell 2.0 cmdlet.

So if you do:

```
Test-Connection -count 2 -quiet
```

it will send 2 ICMP packets and return $true if any are successful or $false if all are dropped.

Comment: thank a lot. i was struggling with it and was looking to timeout wmi calls